# Casbah returns DBObject instead of MongoDBObject

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

In the official [Casbah guide on querying](https://mongodb.github.io/casbah/guide/querying.html) it says

> findOne Returns an Option - either Some(MongoDBObject) or None

However, `findOne` actually gives me an `Option` with a plain `Some(DBObject)` instead:

```
scala> MongoClient("localhost", 27017)("db")("collection").findOne()

res0: Option[com.mongodb.DBObject] = Some({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "559860491b07c0dc5b52f3ee"} , "description" : "Some text" })
```

The same happens with `find`, it returns an iterator over `DBObject` instances. After hours of googling and scratching my head I'm at a loss.

What's going on here? I'm still learning Scala so there might be some nuance that I'm not getting.

Comment: The examples in the [tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.0/tutorial.html) return plain `DBObject`s, so possibly this is just an error in the documentation? And I think casbah provides implicit (automatic) conversions between `DBObject` and `MongoDBObject` - see [here](https://osdir.com/ml/mongodb-user/2011-02/msg02745.html) and [here](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.0/tutorial.html#mongodbobject-a-scala-ble-dbobject-implementation)

Comment: You're right, thank you! What I missed was the import of `com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._`, the implicit conversion worked after that. I kinda wish they would have made that more clear in the guide.

Comment: Great! - I'll add that as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples in the tutorial return plain `DBObject`s, so I think this is just a mistake in the documentation.

Casbah provides implicit (automatic) conversions between `DBObject` and `MongoDBObject` - as described here:

- [Tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.0/tutorial.html#mongodbobject-a-scala-ble-dbobject-implementation)

> There is an implicit conversion loaded that can Pimp any DBObject as MongoDBObject

- [mongodb-user mailing list thread](https://osdir.com/ml/mongodb-user/2011-02/msg02745.html)

> We automatically provide implicit methods which convert DBObject to
>   MongoDBObject. Any method which needs a MongoDBObject will accept a
>   DBObject fine as long as you ran the imports.

You will need to import the conversions for this to work, using:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
```